# Using .css like a toggleclass

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that will change the CSS of the .flavor box with toggleClass and also add some text to the bottom. I want to change this so that when I click my box again (it is already active), the .active-text disappears also. How can I do this? Thanks!

```
$(".flavor").click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("flavor-active");
    $(this).find('.active-text').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for the class you're toggling

```
$(".flavor").click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass("flavor-active")
           .find('.active-text') 
           .css('visibility', $(this).hasClass('flavor-active') ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(this).find('.active-text').toggle()
```

Alternatively, if `.active-text` is a child of `.flavor` you can use CSS like this:

```
.flavor .active-text { display:none; }
.flavor-active .active-text { display:block; /* or inline, just not hidden */ }
```